# React Formik does not work with number input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, formik

Using `Formik` with `Ant Design`, here is a simple setup.

You can see the entire code pasted here:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import { Formik } from "formik";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber } from "antd";

function App() {
  const name = "name";
  const count = "count";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Formik Testing</h1>

      <Formik
        initialValues={{ count: 32, name: "sd" }}
        validate={async values => {
          console.log("Validate", values);
          return {
            count: `Value ${values.count} is not valid.`
          };
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
        render={props => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Form>
                <Form.Item help={props.errors && props.errors[name]}>
                  <Input
                    id={name}
                    name={name}
                    type={"text"}
                    onChange={v => {
                      console.log("Text change ", v);
                      props.handleChange(v);
                    }}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                    defaultValue={props.initialValues[name]}
                    placeholder="Name"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item help={props.errors && props.errors[count]}>
                  <InputNumber
                    id={count}
                    name={count}
                    type={"number"}
                    onChange={v => {
                      console.log("Number change ", v);
                      props.handleChange(v);
                    }}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                    defaultValue={props.initialValues[count]}
                    placeholder="Count"
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So basically:

- `handleChange` is called correctly by the `InputNumber` component
- validation is **not** triggered when the number field changes
- validation is triggered when the text field changes
- validation is triggered with the default value when `onblur` (after clicking away from the input number field)

This seems like a bug, but I assume I am doing something wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Code in action:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-architecture-0c8p2

*(The preview css seems to have a bug - in case you see multiple arrows, use the top one only)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Formik's built in `setFieldValue` function to define your own change handler for the input which will set the number value directly:

```
           <InputNumber
                    id={count}
                    name={count}
                    type={"number"}
                    onChange={v => {
                      props.setFieldValue(count, v);
                    }}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                    defaultValue={props.initialValues[count]}
                    placeholder="Count"
                  />
```

According to [the docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik) it also has a third boolean argument to determine whether or not to run validation.  So passing in `true` after `v` should trigger validation if `validateOnChange` is enabled on the main `Formik` component.

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with `antd`, but what i see is that when i change `InputNumber` to `Input` it works.

Basically, `InputNumber` is giving you the value back instead of the object like `Input`.

From `antd` docs:

`Input -> onChange -> function(e)`
which is the SyntheticEvent

`InputNumber -> onChange -> function(value: number | string)`
just a value

Comment: Now I realized that Formik does not know what value should change when calling `handleChange` with just a single number. But why is it allowed then? And while your solution seems to solve the issue, `InputNumber` has more features than `Input`. Do you know how I to call `handleChange` with specifying what field has been changed?

Comment: And I just realized the `handleChange` is actually `handleChange<T = unknown | React.ChangeEvent<any>>(field: T): T extends React.ChangeEvent<any> ? void : ((e: unknown | React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void);` So I guess I'll have to find out how to create a `React.ChangeEvent` for that component.

Comment: Im not saying changing InputNumber to Input is the solution, im only sharing my observations. InputNumber is just lacking their, so its a antd thing, not a Formik one.

Comment: This could be a work around. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void

Edited: I see that Rutherford came with this solution as well